# What is the scope of NUnit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

Can anyone tell me what is the scope for someone doing NUnit testing or basically Unit testing in future? Is it in any way different from what QA people do?

Answer (score 1):

Unit testing is not for QA (they usually do acceptance testing). It's for developers. Unit testing helps you to do regression testing of your system, but main benefit of unit testing is system designing when you do Test Driven Development. It is also very useful during refactoring when you want to keep behavior of your code unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

**Distinction of unit testing over conventional software testing**:

- when the test is written: usually before the productive code
- who writes the test: the developer
- how much the test writer knows about the code under test: white box
- how test writing is integrated in the development cycle (TDD):

  1. Add a test
  2. Run all tests and see if the new one fails
  3. Write some code
  4. Run tests
  5. Refactor code
  6. Repeat

**Advantages**:

- this kind of developing improves the design of object interactions from the start
- the test represents a reliable documentation of the behavior (strictly speaking: any other behavior is undefined)
- it demonstrates the usage of the class under test
- errors resulting from code changes are detected immediately

Comment: What is the scope for a B.Tech fresher? I mean Career wise?

Comment: @user2991609: Isn't that [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)?

Answer (score 1):

A short answer is yes and no. Unit tests can successfully replace the QA people for a good part of their duties, so in this sense they both fulfill the same need.

A distinction is that unit testing kills the turn-around time for bugs, and it will also help not create legacy code witch seams not to have meaning. If you change something in code and the unit tests fail, this will be immediate(unit-test-run time), if you need the QA people to do it, it might take them days to find the problem(if they find it)
. 
Also unit tests will fail on specific tasks witch will tell you with more accuracy what and where something went wrong. QA people will report a bug, and there is a possibility that you will have to dig deep to actually find the root cause.

In general unit testing is speeds up development and helps the developer find the root of problems faster, and and it also makes the QA's job a lot easier and faster.

Comment: what is the scope for a B.Tech fresher? Career wise..I am using NUnit testing?

Comment: @user2991609 I'm sorry I am not familiar with the B.Tech acronym. If you are asking what is the carer path for somebody starting out as a unit test writer then I can say in my opinion it is rather slim. But it is a good start for becoming a full developer or QA engineer..

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone tell me what is the scope for someone doing NUnit testing or basically Unit testing in future?

NUnit is an unit testing framework for .NET. However, **using it doesn't guarantee you're writing unit tests**. You can write not only unit, but also other kind of tests: integration, functional and acceptance tests.

NUnit can be used by a software developer, automation developer and by QA as well.

- **Software developers** usually writes unit tests in Test-Driven Development process. They may also write acceptance and/or integration tests.
- **Automation developers** or **software developers in tests** may write acceptance and/or integration tests.

> Is it in any way different from what QA people do?

Yes, it is different. QA is doing manual UI debugging and focuses on bugs in real world scenarios. QA is not interested if `IsValidated` should return true in some cases (that's an unit test), but is interested if there are any bugs in real world scenarios (user acceptance's tests). As Osherove pointed in "Art of Unit Testing" book: *Unit tests provide the first layer of defense against bugs, and QA work provides the second layer—the user’s acceptance layer.*

QA **may assist** with writing unit tests in places where QA writes a code. They can help software developers to write such tests but they never should creates unit tests for them.

---

If you are interested in Test-Driven Development and unit testing, I recommend you a book The [*Art of Unit Testing: With examples in C#* (Second Edition)](http://www.manning.com/osherove2).